# Soap Envelope HTML Payload issue com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected '&lt;'

Tags: soap, coldfusion, soapui, cfml, cfc

I'm working on the legacy soap API to modify. I have to add an email body in the payload when I'm sending simple text it works fine when I send `"<p>test</p>"` or HTML it gives me an error.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected '&lt;'  in attribute value
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [32,57]</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

my soap API written in ColdFusion 10

XSD

```
<xs:element name="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType mixed = "true">
    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="value" use="required"  type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Does this help? You could parse the HTML for special characters and replace them with encoded. I am unfamiliar with CDATA but that also looks like it might work.  http://www.zerogbram.com/2015/08/send-passing-html-markup-in-soap-xml-as.html

Comment: thank you for the quick response shared link was great but some CDATA did not work

Answer (score 1):

You want to use encodeForXML (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforxml.html) to escape the content first. If that's not available in CF10, the older XmlFormat (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/xmlformat.html).